# Flutter/Dart Import files at runtime

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two files named

`abc.dart`

```
String one = "One";
String two = "Two";
```

and `xyz.dart`

```
String one = "1";
String two = "2";
```

In my app, I have a `bool` value, if it is `true` I want to use `one` as `"One"` and if `false`, `one` should be `"1"`.

That is I need to import `abc.dart` on `true` and `xyz.dart` on `false`.

Comment: According to this [issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/10530), it seems there is not possible in Flutter. Anyway, I can suggest a solution if you tell me whether the `bool` value is a constant or how it is is calculated.

Comment: @mutasaki the `bool` value isn't a constant, it can be changed on a button click.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/10530#issuecomment-450510757), it seems there is not possible in Flutter.

This is because a Flutter app is compiled AOT (ahead of time), so it needs to load all the sources at compile time.

So, instead of counting on dynamic modules imports, your options are:

- using compile time constants

```
// letter.dart
class Letters {
  final String one;
  final String two;

  const Letter(this.one, this.two);
}

// abc.dart
const ABC = Letters('one', two');

// xyz.dart
const XYZ = Letters('1', 2');


// main
import './abc.dart'
import './xyz.dart'

onPressedHandler() {
  print(boolValue? abc.one : xyz.one);
}
```

- specify the files as assets and parse them in run time.[documentation about using assets](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#loading-text-assets)

Comment: Thanks for giving me an idea.